# Neat: Dynamically increasing column width while maintaining grid structure

Tags: css, neat

I'm using Bourbon's Neat library for my grid system.

I have some code like this:

```
section {
  @include outer-container;
  aside { @include span-columns(3); }
  article { @include span-columns(9); }
}
```

I want to increase the width of the `aside` tag by, let's say, 50px on hover. However,this will cause the `article` to be pushed down to the next line.

Is there a way to scale the width of one column and proportionally resize the other column?

I know this can be done with javascript but I was wondering if there is a way to do this with the Neat grid-system .

Thanks!

---

**EDIT**

Here is the solution that worked for me:

```
section {
  @include outer-container;
  aside { 
    @include span-columns(3);

    &:hover {
      @include span-columns(2);

      & + article {
        @include span-columns(11);
      }
    }
  }
  article { @include span-columns(9); }
}
```

I'm using the css sibling selector `+` to select the article element when the `aside` is being hovered over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no built-in functionality for this, but have you tried overriding `width` on `:hover`? That is to say, add `x` length to the `width` of Column A and take the same amount *away* from Column B. CSS `calc()` could help here.

Neat’s docs give insight into the exact function of `span-columns` and its output: http://thoughtbot.github.io/neat-docs/latest/#span-columns

That being said, this sounds like a great use case for flexbox, if your needs allow for that.

Comment: Hi Tyler, I can increase width of Col A on `:hover` however, I don't think I can increase the width of Col B since it is a sibling of Col A rather than a child.

Comment: Tyler, my bad. You can use a sibling selector to override the width. I've edited my question with the solution.